# iOS Swift Objective-C with bridging header sqlite3 sqlite3_create_function error: ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

When I call sqlite3_create_function I am receiving an error. The XCode "hint" for the problem indicates that "&distanceFunc" is where the problem is coming in at. Here is the code:

```
var myDB : sqlite3_file
var sqliteDatabasePtr = sqlite3_open("septaStopsDB", nil)
sqlite3_create_function(sqliteDatabasePtr, "distance", 4, SQLITE_UTF8, nil, &distanceFunc, nil, nil);
```

"Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

I would be very grateful for help in understanding how I can correctly place the code here.

And where is this function coming from? I am creating a Swift project which uses sqlite3.  I have created a bridging header file to Objective C and added the sqlite3 library to the project build settings. I see the autocomplete for the sqlite C functions in Swift so I know the bridge is working.

I know there are "fully Swift" solutions for sqlite3 but I need certain functions from the dylib (such sqlite3_create_function so I can create a function for cos )

The basic outline of the sqlite function is [here at this link](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html)